# How to debug mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm making a pong game trying to script it only in jquery. I've seen plugins but would rather try and handcode it.  My code as is allows me to move my object('#r') up and down but only if its sitting along the same x axis and is a bit buggy.  I want it to do it regardless of where the mouse is on the body.

```
$("body").mousemove(function(e) {

    $("#r").css('top',e.pageY)

});
```

This is the code-snippet in my javascript file

Comment: Ouch. Performing that selector in that handler is going to be slow. You should probably run the selector outside the function handler.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? How to debug this? use `console.log`

Comment: No its working.  but how do you move it up and down regardless of where the mouse is on Y coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You can show the information you want on the console, by example:

```
console.log(e.pageY)
```

Even if i don't know what you want to debug exactly...

Comment: the question is how to move the object up and down regardless where the Y coordinate is.

Answer (score 0):

A trick for mousemove debug.

```
function triggerOnEachMouseMoveEvent(e)
{
       if(e.ctrlKey) debugger; 

       ...
}
```

So when you press ctrl you will stop at the beginning of your code block.